# Inserción dinamica a una propiedad en un arreglo JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, array, bucle-for, validación

Buenos tardes tengo un problema al tratar de insertar un valor dinámico en una propiedad de un arreglo. cada objeto tiene una propiedad que define el tipo de dato de cada objeto ejemplo: NUMBER, STRING. y tengo una propiedad llamada campoDb en el cual debo darle un índice dinámico a esa propiedad por ejemplo:

En el bucle de abajo se crea 8 objetos correctamente, los 4 primeros objetos el campoDb esta correcto pero los siguientes 4 objetos están mal.

```
  0  {nombre: "ORDEN", campoDb: "NUMBER1", valor: 34},    
  1 {nombre: "CONTRAPARTIDA", campoDb: "STRING1", valor: "vcd"},   
  2 {nombre: "NOMBRE", campoDb: "STRING2", valor: "abc"},    
  3 {nombre: "VALOR ENV.", campoDb: "NUMBER1", valor: 12}
  // hasta el objeto 4 esta correcto.
  4 {nombre: "ORDEN", campoDb: "NUMBER3", valor: 33},    
  5 {nombre: "CONTRAPARTIDA", campoDb: "STRING3", valor: "sds"},   
  6 {nombre: "NOMBRE", campoDb: "STRING4", valor: "ffd"},    
  7 {nombre: "VALOR ENV.", campoDb: "NUMBER4", valor: 3}
```

```js
let columnas = [];

//Arreglo de columnas tipo de dato
let columnaServicio = [
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 1,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "ORDEN",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "NUMBER",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7
    },
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 2,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "CONTRAPARTIDA",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "STRING",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7
    },
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 3,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "NOMBRE",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "STRING",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7 
    },
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 4,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "VALOR ENV.",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "NUMBER",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7
    }
    ]

//Arreglo de información
let val = [
           {
              "Contrapartida": "llgfhfg",
              "Fecha de Depósito": 44040,
              "Forma pago:": "FE",
              "No. referencia": 10645124,
              "Nombre": "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
              "Orden": 1,
              "Valor env.": 4.22
          },
          {
              "Contrapartida": "sdsdsd",
              "Fecha de Depósito": 334232,
              "Forma pago": "FE",
              "No. referencia": 33434,
              "Nombre": "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
              "Orden": 2,
              "Valor env.": 444
          }
                ]
         numbersCount = 0 // CONTADOR DE NUMBERS
         stringCount = 0  // CONTADOR DE STRING
     //inicio de los bucles    
    for(let k = 0; k < val.length; k++){
       for(let y = 0; y < columnaServicio.length; y++){
           columnas.push({
           "nombre": columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE,
           "tipo": columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO,
           "fila": k + 1,
           "campoDb":  columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO + ( (columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO == 'STRING' ? ++stringCount : ++numbersCount) ),
                });  
                   }
                    }
 console.log("columnas: ", columnas)
```

ya que el 5to elemento es similar al 1ro solo que cambia el contenido de la propiedad valor, lo que deseo hacer es que todo objeto que tenga el mismo valor de la propiedad nombre adquiera automáticamente el valor de la propiedad campoDb. el arreglo deberia quedar así:

```
  0 {nombre: "ORDEN", campoDb: "NUMBER1", valor: 34},    
  1 {nombre: "CONTRAPARTIDA", campoDb: "STRING1", valor: "vcd"},   
  2 {nombre: "NOMBRE", campoDb: "STRING2", valor: "abc"},    
  3 {nombre: "VALOR ENV.", campoDb: "NUMBER1", valor: 12}
  // hasta el objeto 4 esta correcto.
  4 {nombre: "ORDEN", campoDb: "NUMBER1", valor: 33},    
  5 {nombre: "CONTRAPARTIDA", campoDb: "STRING1", valor: "sds"},   
  6 {nombre: "NOMBRE", campoDb: "STRING2", valor: "ffd"},    
  7 {nombre: "VALOR ENV.", campoDb: "NUMBER2", valor: 3}
```

lo que necesito es que saber como podría corregir este error o que opción podría implementar para realizar lo que necesito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que falta hacer es validar si ya existe el registro anterior, para ello tienes que realizar otro ciclo para buscar si el nombre ya existe, así cuando vayas a insertar, se verifica si existe el mismo nombre y tomas el campoDb, si no, usas los contadores para registros nuevos, la corrección del código quedaría de la siguiente forma.

```js
let columnas = [];

//Arreglo de columnas tipo de dato
let columnaServicio = [
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 1,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "ORDEN",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "NUMBER",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7
    },
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 2,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "CONTRAPARTIDA",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "STRING",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7
    },
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 3,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "NOMBRE",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "STRING",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7 
    },
    {
    "uztfilecolumn_ID": 4,
    "uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE": "VALOR ENV.",
    "uztfilecolumn_NULL": "N",
    "uztfilecolumn_TIPO": "NUMBER",
    "uztproc_ID": 3,
    "uztsist_ID": 7
    }
    ]

//Arreglo de información
let val = [
    {
        "Contrapartida": "llgfhfg",
        "Fecha de Depósito": 44040,
        "Forma pago:": "FE",
        "No. referencia": 10645124,
        "Nombre": "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
        "Orden": 1,
        "Valor env.": 4.22
    },
    {
        "Contrapartida": "sdsdsd",
        "Fecha de Depósito": 334232,
        "Forma pago": "FE",
        "No. referencia": 33434,
        "Nombre": "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
        "Orden": 2,
        "Valor env.": 444
    }
]
numbersCount = 0 // CONTADOR DE NUMBERS
stringCount = 0  // CONTADOR DE STRING

//inicio de los bucles    
for(let k = 0; k < val.length; k++){
    for(let y = 0; y < columnaServicio.length; y++){
        let campoDb = null;
        
        if (columnas.length > 0){
            for(let x= 0; x < columnas.length; x++){
                if (columnas[x].nombre == columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE){
                    campoDb = columnas[x].campoDb;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (campoDb != null){
            columnas.push({
                "nombre": columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE,
                "tipo": columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO,
                "fila": k + 1,
                "campoDb": campoDb,
            });
        }else{
            columnas.push({
                "nombre": columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_NOMBRE,
                "tipo": columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO,
                "fila": k + 1,
                "campoDb":  columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO + ( columnaServicio[y].uztfilecolumn_TIPO == 'STRING' ? ++stringCount : ++numbersCount ),
            });
        }
    }
}
console.log("columnas: ", columnas)
```

Cuando inserto el registro, realizo el ciclo y lo detengo cuando detecte que ya existe el nombre en el arreglo, tomo el campoDb y con un if filtro en caso de que no exista el nombre

Comment: muchas gracias, me ayudo mucho tu respuesta